# How to add boolean string to plist with theos tweak?

Tags: iphone, plist, boolean, tweak

Well i need to create a tweak that adds for example boolean string **test** in **/var/mobile/test.plist** in **dict** dictionary with

Answer (score 0):

[dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"myKey"];